# Reverse looping with dates in vbscript

Tags: for-loop, vbscript

in VBScript, we can loop between 2 dates, using:

```
for k = date() to date()+4
  ...
next
```

But if I want the loop to be in reverse, neither of the following work:

```
for k = date()+4 to date()

for k = date() to date()-4 step-1
```

They just give an empty loop.

Is there a way to do this? I need the dates in descending order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really?, your last example works for me.
Would have posted this as a comment but wanted to show the output working, your code seems fine.

```
Dim k
For k = Date() To Date() - 4 Step - 1
  WScript.Echo k
Next
```

Output:

```
21/03/2016
20/03/2016
19/03/2016
18/03/2016
17/03/2016
```

Comment: You are right. not sure what i did before. Thank you.